# Looking for a platform/site where I can render my scene at no cost

Tags: rendering

I am creating my first Animated Short. I'm right on the path :). But there is a problem it took too long to Render.
I want any site where I can render my scene with no cost.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First - **there is no free rendering.**

With that out of the way here is one option - https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/

If you ask me, your best bet would be to optimize your own setup or if you are planning on seriously getting into Blender invest into a rendering setup. 
What are you trying to render and what is your setup(both hardware and settings in Blender).

Comment: In Sheepit-renderfarm I read in FAQ:
Is it really free?
Yes, it is! We don't have any hidden tax like paying to get the final result, everything will be free. We only rely on donation and ads to pay for the domain, server and development. You can donate on this page. We accept PayPal, bitcoin and dogecoin.

Comment: Thats True or not?

Comment: The service is free, but your electricity and hardware isn't. If other people are rendering for you, you also have to render for them. The principle is that if you render other peoples stuff for a month, they can together render a month worth of rendertime for you in a much shorter period.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one computer at home you can use the free **Crowdrender** add-on for Blender available at https://www.crowdrender.com.au and benefit from the power of all your hardware